# Can't Reinstall Ubuntu-Desktop due to strange error with printer-driver-pnm2ppa

Tags: drivers, apt, printing, dpkg

I've been trying to fix this error for hours with no avail. My apt-get seems to be paralyzed by an error I'm receiving with this printer-driver-pnm2ppa.  I don't actually need the driver but it's a dependency for a seemingly infinite amount of things.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ubuntu-desktop
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 4,270 B of archives.
After this operation, 60.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main ubuntu-desktop i386 1.307     [4,270 B]
Fetched 4,270 B in 0s (13.7 kB/s)         
Selecting previously unselected package ubuntu-desktop.
(Reading database ... 403424 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking ubuntu-desktop (from .../ubuntu-desktop_1.307_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-13-generic
Processing triggers for ca-certificates ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....
done.
done.
Setting up printer-driver-pnm2ppa (1.13+nondbs-0ubuntu3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/printer-driver-pnm2ppa.postinst: 19: /var/lib/dpkg/info/printer-    driver-pnm2ppa.postinst: install: not found
dpkg: error processing printer-driver-pnm2ppa (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on printer-driver-pnm2ppa; however:
  Package printer-driver-pnm2ppa is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error     from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 printer-driver-pnm2ppa
 ubuntu-desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT 1: By request, adding output of

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install printer-driver-pnm2ppa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  magicfilter apsfilter
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  printer-driver-pnm2ppa
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/210 kB of archives.
After this operation, 772 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-pnm2ppa.
(Reading database ... 403352 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking printer-driver-pnm2ppa (from .../printer-driver-pnm2ppa_1.13+nondbs-0ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for doc-base ...
Processing 3 changed doc-base files...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Setting up printer-driver-pnm2ppa (1.13+nondbs-0ubuntu3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/printer-driver-pnm2ppa.postinst: 19: /var/lib/dpkg/info/printer-    driver-pnm2ppa.postinst: install: not found
dpkg: error processing printer-driver-pnm2ppa (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered     while processing:
 printer-driver-pnm2ppa
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT 2:

```
sudo apt-get purge printer-driver-pnm2ppa && sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/printer-    driver-pnm2ppa*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  printer-driver-pnm2ppa*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 772 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 403423 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing printer-driver-pnm2ppa ...
Purging configuration files for printer-driver-pnm2ppa ...
Processing triggers for doc-base ...
Processing 3 removed doc-base files...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/dpkg/info/printer-driver-pnm2ppa*’: No such file or     directory
```

EDIT 3: Still not working.  Going to report the error to launchpad.

```
 sudo apt-get install printer-driver-pnm2ppa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  magicfilter apsfilter
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  printer-driver-pnm2ppa
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/210 kB of archives.
After this operation, 772 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-pnm2ppa.
(Reading database ... 403352 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking printer-driver-pnm2ppa (from .../printer-driver-pnm2ppa_1.13+nondbs-    0ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for doc-base ...
Processing 3 added doc-base files...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Setting up printer-driver-pnm2ppa (1.13+nondbs-0ubuntu3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/printer-driver-pnm2ppa.postinst: 19: /var/lib/dpkg/info/printer-driver-pnm2ppa.postinst: install: not found
dpkg: error processing printer-driver-pnm2ppa (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 printer-driver-pnm2ppa
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get --reinstall install printer-driver-pnm2ppa`?

Comment: Just added it.  Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Ok, seem that one script is missing... somehow. Do, `sudo apt-get purge printer-driver-pnm2ppa && sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/printer-driver-pnm2ppa*`.

Comment: Done.  Should I try to install it again or do it differently somehow?

Comment: Now install it again, if it fails then is a bug in the package and you should report it to launchpad.

Comment: Seems like it's a bug.  Is there any way I can get around it for now so I can still use my computer for other things?

Comment: One last try... what is the output of `type install`?

Comment: install is /usr/bin/install . Comments?